# Getting selected checkboxes in a gridview in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, gridview, checkbox

I am using a gridview in asp.net with the left column being checkboxes. How can I tell which rows have a checkbox "checked" upon button submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Adding a GridView Column of Checkboxes](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/adding-a-gridview-column-of-checkboxes-vb)

[Adding checkbox column to GridView dynamically](http://www.vbknowledgebase.com/?Id=90&Desc=Adding-checkbox-column-to-GridView-dynamically) (on VB.NET)

Answer (score 1):

```
CheckBox chkBx = new CheckBox();

for (int i = 0; i < grdView.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
chkBx = (CheckBox)grdView.Rows[i].FindControl("yourCheckBoxIDInHTMLView");

 if (chkBx.Checked == true)
 {
  // Do some work here
 }
}
```